# php display data in div, h1, ul using while loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I am not very good in php and mysql but based on my code, I am able to display the results that I wanted but, it is not displaying in the right DOM structure.

I would like to display like below:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Header</h1>
<ul><li>
<p>data 1</p>
<p>data 2</p>
</li></ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
<h1>Header</h1>
<ul><li>
<p>data 1</p>
<p>data 2</p>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

I have no idea why my code keep returning me the data and display everything in the 1st level ul instead of separating like below:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Header</h1>
<ul><li>
<p>data1</p>
<p>data 2</p>

<div class="container">
<h1>Header</h1>
<ul><li>
<p>data1</p>
<p>data 2</p>
</li></ul>
</div>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

I have played around with the code and tried different ways but still unable to get it display properly. Below is my code:

```
<?php
        $data='';
        $previousVal = '';
        // Update new images
        $levelArray=array('B1','L1','L2','main','L3','L4','L5');
            foreach ($levelArray as $i=>$level) {
                $img = "img/".$level.".jpg";
                if($level=='main'){
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM floor_directory ORDER BY categories");
                }
                else {
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM floor_directory WHERE level='$level' ORDER BY categories");
                }

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    if($previousVal != $row['categories']){
                         $data .= '<div class="container"><h1>'.$row['categories'].'</h1>';
                         $previousVal = $row['categories'];
                    }
                     $data .= '<ul><li>
                               <p class="float_left">'.$row['name'].'</p>
                               <p class="float_right">'.$row['unit_number'].'</p>
                               </li></ul></div>';
                }

                if($levelArray[$i]=='main'){
                    echo '<div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="'.$img.'" alt="" />
                        <div class="content_container_main">'.$data.'</div>
                  </div>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="'.$img.'" alt="" />
                        <div class="content_container">'.$data.'</div>
                  </div>';
                }
                $data='';
                $previousVal = '';
            }
         ?>
```

Hope you guys understand. Thanks in advance for the help guys.

Comment: Separate your database handling code from HTML handling code

Comment: Also take advantage of MySQLi's ability and use [variable binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of stuffing everything into SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks both for the reply. Is the thing that you 2 mentioned an advanced level? =x

Answer (score 0):

changing code in while will make it work, change this code,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  if($previousVal != $row['categories']){
    $data .= '<div class="container"><h1>'.$row['categories'].'</h1>';
    $previousVal = $row['categories'];
  }
  $data .= '<ul><li>
  <p class="float_left">'.$row['name'].'</p>
  <p class="float_right">'.$row['unit_number'].'</p>
  </li></ul></div>';
}
```

with this,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  if($previousVal != $row['categories']){
    $previousVal = $row['categories'];
  }
  $data .= '<div class="container"><h1>'.$row['categories'].'</h1>';
  $data .= '<ul><li>
  <p class="float_left">'.$row['name'].'</p>
  <p class="float_right">'.$row['unit_number'].'</p>
  </li></ul></div>';
}
```

you may even remove the if check (inside while loop) if not using in further script.

Comment: Hi Adil, thanks for the help but the $data in the if check was supposed to show only the header of different data 1 time instead of showing the header repeatedly. That explains the if check which was there.